# How to control if the result of the query is null or empty

Tags: c#, .net

I have SqlConnection in my project and i want to control to my query result

```
public IEnumerable<Product> ListPrpductByCategory(int ID)
{

    var dr = db.ExecuteReader(@"SELECT P.ID,P.CategoryID,P.Name,P.SupplierID,p.UnitPrice,p.UnitsInStock,pp.PicturePath 
                                FROM Products P 
                                LEFT JOIN ProductPhoto PP ON p.ID=PP.ProductID   
                                WHERE P.CategoryID=@ID",
                                Values: new object[] { ID });
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        yield return new Product()
        {
            ID = dr.GetInt32(0),
            CategoryID = dr.GetInt32(1),
            SupplierID = dr.GetInt32(3),
            Name = dr.GetString(2),
            UnitPrice = dr.GetDecimal(4),
            UnitInstock = dr.GetInt16(5),
            PicturePath = dr.GetString(6)
        };
    }
    dr.Close();

    //...
}
```

If there is no picture it throw me error I want to control `dr.GetString(6)`
like

```
if(dr.GetString(6)==null)
    PicturePath="Noimage.jpg";
```

how can I do that?

Comment: thank u llya ıt worked :)

Answer (score 3):

I usually write those as:

```
PicturePath = dr.IsDBNull(6) ? "Noimage.jpg" : dr.GetString(6)
```

Also, you should wrap the data reader in a `using` statement:

```
using(var dr = db.ExecuteReader(...))
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        ...
    }
} //no need to call Close, as Dispose already closes the reader.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [null-coalescing operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator)

```
PicturePath = GetString(6) ?? "Noimage.jpg",
```

Comment: ?? won't work as it would call dr.GetString anyway, which will still throw when the value at the 6th field is DBNull.Value. Not sure why the OP says it worked in the comment above. There is no way it can, unless he looked at a different record.

Comment: Well, see the comment made by Burak to his question. I was analysing simple API for `GetString(int)`, which as he said, can simply return null.

Answer (score 1):

Try [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx):

```
if(dr.IsDBNull(6))
PicturePath = "Noimage.jpg";
else
PicturePath = dr.GetString(6);
```